# Getting files off bcache disk from different computer

Tags: arch-linux, data-recovery, bcache

I have a disk with a btrfs filesystem on top of bcache that was used in an old installation I no longer have (unintentionally nuked). When I plug in the drive, /dev/bcache0 doesn't show up and I'm not allowed to echo `/dev/{dev}` into `/sys/fs/bcache/register` to force it. I have the bcache module loaded, and when I try to rmmod it I get a "module in use" message. `lsblk -f` indicates that bcache is present on the drive, but I can't map it to get to the btrfs filesystem underneath and recover my data.

I don't think it matters, but this is all on top of a dmcrypt encrypted volume, which I have the keyfile for and is accessible without problems.

`System information
Distro: Arch
Kernel: 4.12.5-1-ARCH x86_64
bcache Version: 1.0.8-1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mounted the bcache partition to a loop device with `sudo losetup -f /dev/[DEVICE] -o 8192` The bcache data is probably only 1KiB or less, but the offset needs to align with the sector size of the disk, in this case 8KiB. This worked perfectly and I've been transferring files to a stable storage pool overnight.

If anyone else finds themselves stuck with this issue, get the sector size of your disk with `sudo smartctl -a /dev/[DEVICE]` (needs smartmontools package) and use increments of that size as an offset with the losetup command I mentioned earlier until the loop device shows a filesystem present when `lsblk -f` is run.

Answer (score 1):

To extend PSpacer's answer based on answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820492/how-to-revert-bcache-device-to-regulare-filesystem)

> D) Recovering data without bcache:
>
> If bcache is not available in the kernel, a filesystem on the backing
>   device is still available at an 8KiB offset. So either via a loopdev
>   of the backing device created with --offset 8K, or any value defined by
>   --data-offset when you originally formatted bcache with `make-bcache`.
>
> For example:
>       `losetup -o 8192 /dev/loop0 /dev/your_bcache_backing_dev`

From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/bcache.txt.

**Create Loopback Device**

Create a loopback device via `sudo losetup -o 8192 /dev/loop0 /dev/[DEVICE]`

**Mount Device**

You can then mount this via `sudo mount /dev/loop0 -o loop /mnt/[LOCATION]`

After this you can go to `/mnt/[LOCATION]/` and browse your partition.